# C : load of null pointer of type 'int' (__Serializer__.c), Error in my code

Tags: c

My code for the above problem received the following runtime error
"Line 207: Char 3: runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int' (**Serializer**.c)"
Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong.
My code:

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize)
{
    int x=0,i,j;
    returnSize = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<numsSize; i++)
        {
        x = nums[i];
            for (j=i+1; j<numsSize; j++)
            {
             if (nums[j] == target-x)
                {   
                    returnSize[0] = i;
                    returnSize[1] = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
   return *returnSize;
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 207? (And I am almost sure you want to return `returnSize`, not `*returnSize`.)

Comment: So did you check if `returnSize` or `nums` are `NULL`? `return *returnSize;` - is this intended to return `int` cast to `int*`? Did you enable compiler warnings?

Comment: the return! you need to return a pointer not a de refrence!! return the pointer you have recieved from malloc. This code have too many problems to discuss, checking malloc return value, names of varibles, checking input parameters and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
int* twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int* p_retval_size)
{
int x=0,i,j;
int* p_retval = NULL;

/*check inputs*/
if(!nums || numSize < D_SOME_PREDEFINED_VALUE || !(p_retval = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int)))
{
    *p_retval_size=0;
    return p_retval;
}

/*do the function work */

*p_retval_size = 2;
return p_retval;
}
```

in the above code you can see some of the fixes to your function!